# Magento 2.2.5: Error on running setup: upgrade after upgrading Magento from 2.2.2 to 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, sales, cli, setup-upgrade, magento-upgrade

I am facing issues with Magento Upgrade from **2.2.2** to **2.2.5**. After upgraded, I ran setup:upgrade command several times, but each time It takes too much time in **Module_Sales** upgrading data.
After taking so long, It returns error We can't save the address, Email has a wrong format.

Can anyone help me? Thank You[image]

Comment: execute this command rm -rf var/ generated/

Comment: Thank you..but Aleady did this @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced with the same issue after upgrade magento to 2.2.5 version.
Also we're using migrated database and I think this is the main key of current error.

I've solved current issue with queries:

```
update quote_address a left join customer_entity o on a.customer_id = 
o.entity_id set a.email = coalesce(o.email, 'noemail@dummy.com') 
where a.email is null

update sales_order_address a left join sales_order o on a.parent_id = 
o.entity_id set a.email = coalesce(o.customer_email, 
'noemail@dummy.com') where a.email is null
```

Briefly, in some quote or sales addresses, email has been missed and we populate it with email of the customer if customer ID not empty, otherwise just added dummy email.

Also it could be useful reference in current question:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14964

Comment: Yes I did similar thing, It helped